# swift4: "cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable" in mutating function

Tags: swift

This code

```
extension Collection {
  mutating func f() {
    removeFirst()
  }
}
```

proces the error

```
cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
```

I think the mutating keyword should make 'self' mutable. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection) is the protocol to which collections
conform if you can add or remove elements:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func f() {
        self.removeFirst()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think the mutating keyword should make 'self' mutable. Why?

If you could simply change an existing protocol or class from immutable to mutable by doing what you tried to do it would be be almost impossible to write frameworks in an efficient and well designed way if the classes couldn't trust there own state or the value of its properties.

This is a necessary constraint and it also follows the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) as I see it.